# Text Box which Blends into background

Tags: wpf, silverlight, windows-phone-7

How do I create a Text Box which Blends into the background page, the idea here is i want to create NoteBook like Effect with lines and user types on lines ( just like writing in Notebook with lines).

Answer (score 5):

Take a `TextBox` with transparent background, put it on top of your notebook paper image and align font size so it looks as desired. You may want to wrap `TextBox` with `ViewBox`

```
 <TextBox TextWrapping="Wrap" Background="{x:Null}"/>
```

Or use a `TextBox` with notebook paper image as background:

```
 <TextBox TextWrapping="Wrap">
    <TextBox.Background>
       <ImageBrush ImageSource="notebook-paper.png"/>
    </TextBox.Background>
 </TextBox>
```

Comment: ...and get rid of the border `BorderBrush="{x:Null}"`

Comment: Or BorderThickness="0"

Answer (score 1):

Style your `TextBox` as required so that the background shows through. To remove the Textbox's background, padding, border, etc., use:

```
<TextBox Margin="0" BorderThickness="0" Padding="0" Background="Transparent" />
```

To control the line height so that it lines up neatly on your notepad line graphic, use the `TextBlock` attached properties:

```
<TextBox
    Margin="0" BorderThickness="0" Padding="0" Background="Transparent"
    TextBlock.LineHeight="10" 
    TextBlock.LineStackingStrategy="BlockLineHeight" />
```

Comment: Are you sure `TextBlock.LineHeight` and `TextBlock.LineStackingStrategy` are actually attached properties? Blend says they *"...can only be applied to types that are derived from TextBlock"* when I tried your sample (i.e. normal Dependency properties).

Comment: VS2010 also says "The attached property LineHeight was not found in type TextBlock"... Are you using an extension to TextBlock that has those as Attached Properties? If so please state.

Answer (score 0):

There is a better way to do this. You can just override default style and make TextBox transparent. Like that.

```
<TextBox Style="{StaticResource TransparentTextBox}"/>
```

Here is that style:

```
<Style x:Key="TransparentTextBox" TargetType="TextBox">
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeMediumLarge}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxForegroundBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="SelectionBackground" Value="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="SelectionForeground" Value="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxSelectionForegroundBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{StaticResource PhoneBorderThickness}"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
                    <Grid Background="Transparent">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="EnabledBorder">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="DisabledOrReadonlyBorder">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="ReadOnly">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="EnabledBorder">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="DisabledOrReadonlyBorder">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="DisabledOrReadonlyBorder">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="DisabledOrReadonlyBorder">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="DisabledOrReadonlyContent">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxReadOnlyBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Focused"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Border x:Name="EnabledBorder" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Margin="{StaticResource PhoneTouchTargetOverhang}">
                            <ContentControl x:Name="ContentElement" BorderThickness="0" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Margin="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxInnerMargin}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" Content="sdasdasd"/>
                        </Border>
                        <Border x:Name="DisabledOrReadonlyBorder" BorderBrush="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="Transparent" Margin="{StaticResource PhoneTouchTargetOverhang}" Visibility="Collapsed">
                            <TextBox x:Name="DisabledOrReadonlyContent" Background="Transparent" Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}" FontWeight="{TemplateBinding FontWeight}" FontStyle="{TemplateBinding FontStyle}" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}" IsReadOnly="True" SelectionForeground="{TemplateBinding SelectionForeground}" SelectionBackground="{TemplateBinding SelectionBackground}" TextAlignment="{TemplateBinding TextAlignment}" TextWrapping="{TemplateBinding TextWrapping}" Text="{TemplateBinding Text}" Template="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledTextBoxTemplate}"/>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Comment: How is writing 81 lines of code better if you can achieve the same with one? ;)

Comment: @StaWho: Agreed... But I can't believe you took the trouble to count the lines :)

Comment: @HiTech Magic: Notepad++, ctrl-c, ctrl-v :)

Comment: @StaWho: Revised... But I can't believe you took the trouble to count the lines *using Notepad++, ctrl-c, ctrl-v* :>

Comment: most of this lines generated by Expression Blend - very useful tool for anyone who works with wpf/silverlight. Also, this way encapsulates styles from layout, which is very important thing when your controls consist of hundreds of lines of code